# Sci fi on TV sticky bomb

Tags: story-identification, tv

I can't remember if it was from a SF film or a TV series, seen in B&W in the 1970s on UK television.

Some humanoid aliens are attacking "the good guys" and their main weapon is throwing these like limpet grenades (iirc they looked a bit like old fashioned alarm clocks) .
The grenades stick to people's torsos and explode after a few seconds.

Update on this after 3 days of hard thinking:-
There were only three good guys and a couple more of the aliens, the action took place indoors in a large room.
I tried searching through episode histories of Phoenix Five but I had no luck. I also unsuccessfully searched through episodes of the Time Tunnel and even Star Maidens.
It's faintly possible that the good guys I remember were members of U.N.I.T but I don't think they wore army uniforms

Edit:- A further thought ..we were only on a black and white TV back in those days, is it possible from an episode of Space 1999?

Comment: Nothing in https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StickyBomb that I can find.

Comment: Found webpage this with a black and white photo, with mines attached to someone's torso: https://armourersbench.com/tag/limpet-bomb/

Comment: Have you taken a look at The Fantastic Journey? US serial from the late 70s but definetly shown on british TV. I can only recall the title so can't say if there is a scene like you describe. Another (very long shot) is that it could be from the Series out of the Unknown. Most episodes of this are now lost so it would be difficult to check on this one.

Comment: might also be worth taking a look at the Doctor Who story Revenge of the Cybermen Could this be the Doctor Who story Revenge of the Cybermen from 1975

This clip shows magnetic bombs that could fit your description of an old fashioned alarm clock.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=ed5hg6tadsQ

Comment: Interesting clip but it wasn't Dr who, the bombs were thrown but they whizzed across the room on a level plane, they were about a quarter of the size of the bombs in the clip, they somehow stuck into the middle of people's chests - I have a memory now of some victim frantically pulling at one to try remove it before it exoloded